# Need to convert a swift snippet of code into Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I had to use swift made code on: https://github.com/lourenco-marinho/ActionButton
but in an Objective-C project. I couldn't convert following swift line into Objective-C:

```
actionButton.action = { button in button.toggleMenu() }
```

**P.S. There is no reference of variable `button` before or after this code**

Let me show how things are defined:

`actionButton` is: `var actionButton: ActionButton!`
and `ActionButton` is an NSObject class

`action` is defined in ActionButton class as: `var action: ActionButtonAction?`

And `ActionButtonAction` is: `typealias ActionButtonAction = (ActionButton) -> Void` defined globally in `ActionButton` class

Pretty Messy? Well, I still want to understand/convert the above swift statement into Objective-C.
For clearance you may follow the link above.

Comment: Objective-C and Swift are bridged: you can invoke a function written in Swift from Objective-C and viceversa.

Comment: Here in the swift statement, actionButton's action variable is being assigned in some mysterious way. How can I do the same in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is block in objective C

```
actionButton.action = ^(ActionButton * button){
    [button toggleMenu];
};
```

Also,typealise converted to objective c is

```
typedef void(^ActionButtonAction)(ActionButton * button);
```